# Tu's - Introduction to Manifolds - Comment on exponential matrix

Tags: manifolds, curves, matrix-exponential, general-linear-group

Can anyone explain to me the meaning of the statement below from [Tu - Introduction to Manifolds](http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf) (specifically section 15.3).

> To compute the differential of a map on a subgroup of $GL(n,R)$, we need a curve
>   of nonsingular matrices. Because the matrix exponential is always nonsingular, it is uniquely suited for this purpose.

Why is the exponential matrix so important? Is it because it represents some sort of parameterization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In this context it is imprtant because, for any square matrix $A$, $e^A$ is nonsingular, since$$\det(e^A)=e^{\operatorname{tr}A}\neq0.$$

Comment: And why is this fact so useful when we talk about curves?

Comment: Because we are interested in curves in $GL(n,\mathbb R)$, which is the space of all $n\times n$ *nonsingular* matrices.

Comment: so to find a curve within $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, one way is to take your favorite curve in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb R^{n^2}$ and then exponentiate the curve.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, can you maybe present an example?

Comment: The curve $t\mapsto\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&t\\t&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ contains singular matrices, but the curve $t\mapsto\exp\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&t\\t&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)$ doesn't.

Comment: I think probably the point I'm missing is why we would pick specifically the exponential map and not some other map that has a similar property (which may or may not exist). Still reading through the book, I think one explantion might be the fact that if we want to compute differentials we can use any curve as long as we know initial point and tangent vector. Since for any $A$ we have $e^A \in GL(\mathbb{R},n)$ I guess what the exponential matrix gives me is a way to construct a curve in that manifold. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but that's what I wrote in my answer. After all, asserting that $e^A$ is nonsingular is *the same thing* as asserting that $e^A\in GL(n,\mathbb R)$, right?!

Comment: You didn't really point out the curve bit in your answer, this is why I was still confused.